# Stop CSS transition from moving text

Tags: css

I have a series of items that when hovered change the border and box-shadow properties. However, during the transition both the text on the page and inside the container move to accommodate the transition. I'm struggling to find a way to stop this from occurring:

```
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="faq-content">
        <span class="faq-icon"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></span>
        <div>
            <a data-modal="#modal1" class="modal-link">Question 1?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.faq-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.faq-container:hover {
    border: 4px solid #0052e7;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-container>div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}

.faq-icon {
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding to the border so that means everything has to shift to accommodate the added pixels in the border.

**Option #1**
Transition the border-color property from transparent to a color. Instead of transitioning the border width.

**Option #2**
Absolutely position the element getting a border so its removed from the DOM flow and can't "move" when you add to the size by changing the border.

**Option #3**
Create another element BEHIND the text container with the border color and then scale that element on hover so it looks like the border expands but its really the thing behind your content scaling so nothing moves.